# Put file from URL to POST request

Tags: php, file, curl, download, upload

I am using PHP script for files uploading to image hosting. Necessary files not stored on disk and available via http URL. So, my first step is to download image to disk:

```
file_put_contents('sample.jpg', file_get_contents($url));
```

And then attach it to curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,      array(
  'image' => '@' . realpath('sample.jpg'),
  'title' => 'sample.jpg'
  ));
```

Am I able to do the same without file downloading: specify URL in parameters for curl to automatically take data from URL?

Comment: I'm not sure about the POST request, but you can try to send it via $_SESSION.

Comment: did u try by putting `$url` in place of `realpath('sample.jpg')`?